# OpenGL and SDL on OSX - EXC_BAD_ACCESS on glDrawElements() - works on GLUT, not with SDL

Tags: opengl, sdl

I wrote a simple application using GLUT that I'm porting to SDL now to turn it into a game.

I am having a bizarre issue specifically with using glDrawElements and Vertex Buffer Objects, SDL 1.2.14 OSX. If I don't use VBO's the program runs fine. It only throws a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when using VBO's. To make the matter more obscure. The program runs totally fine in GLUT. I must be missing something perhaps in my initialization that is causing this.

Here's the drawing code:

```
if (glewGetExtension("GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object"))
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);        

    //Load vertices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->mesh->vbo_vertices);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    //Load normals
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->mesh->vbo_normals);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    //Load UVs
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->mesh->vbo_uvs);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->mesh->vbo_index);
    App dies here -----> glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3*this->mesh->numFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

} else {

    //BTW: If I run this block of code instead of the above, everything renders fine. App doesn't die. 

    //Drawing with vertex arrays
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, this->mesh->vertexArray);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, this->mesh->normalsArray);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, this->mesh->uvArray);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3*this->mesh->numFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, this->mesh->indexArray);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Here's the debug information:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Thread-1-<com.apple.main-thread>
#0  0x17747a93 in gleRunVertexSubmitImmediate
#1  0x1774772c in gleLLVMArrayFunc
#2  0x177476e4 in gleSetVertexArrayFunc
#3  0x1773073c in gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore
#4  0x176baa7b in glDrawElements_Exec
#5  0x97524050 in glDrawElements

asm gleRunVertexSubmitImmediate

0x17747a93  <+0771>  mov    (%eax,%ecx,4),%eax      <-- the app dies on this.
```

Here's my SDL initialization code:

```
//Initialize SDL
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
{
    cout << "Could not initialize SDL" << endl << SDL_GetError();
    exit(2);
}

//Set window
SDL_WM_SetCaption("Hello World!", "Hello World!");

//Set openGL window
if ( SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_RESIZABLE) == NULL ) {
    cout << "Unable to create OpenGL context: %s\n" << endl << SDL_GetError();
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(2);
}

//Set up event handling
SDL_Event event;
bool quit = false;

//Initialize GLEW
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
    //Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. 
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    exit(1);
}
fprintf(stdout, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));
```

Comment: Where are you allocating your VBO IDs (this->mesh->vbo_vertices and friends, I suspect)?

Comment: Yes. the allocation seems fine as I mention, the above works when using GLUT. It is only under SDL that I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.

When you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS, it is typically because of an attempt to access an object that is not allocated, or that has been deallocated.

You can get more detailed debug information on the object in question by enabling the NSZombieEnabled environment variable.  [This](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone) is a simple blog post on how to enable this environment variable (I am not the author).

This will hopefully help get more information in the debug console on why the crash is happening.

Comment: I've enabled the Zombie mode, but it didn't actually change my debug output unfortunately.

Comment: I would start printing out the properties of the mesh before using them in the buffer and draw calls.  mesh->vbo_vertices, mesh->numFaces etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have vn in your model (obj) file, you should comment out the following lines:

```
//glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
//glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

That one worked for me.